# Cartan 3-form on a Lie group G

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mp.mathematical-physics

Does anyone have a reference to learn more about the Cartan $3$-form on a group manifold $G$? I have read that the WZW term is nothing more than the integral of the pullback of the Cartan $3$-form via $g:W\rightarrow G$

$WZW = -\frac{1}{6}\int_W \langle \phi_g\wedge[\phi_g\wedge\phi_g]\rangle$,

where $\phi_g=g^\ast(\phi)$ is the pullback of the Maurer-Cartan form, and would like to learn more about the math behind WZW terms. For eg., why is it the generator of $H^3(G,\mathbb{R})$ when $G$ is a connected, simply connected, compact Lie group?

Comment: What you have written is only the Wess-Zumino term.  The WZW lagrangian also has a standard sigma model term.  Why not read Witten's original paper *Non-abelian bosonization in two dimensions* (CMP 1984)?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry about that. I will edit it now.

Comment: Also, I have tried to go through Witten's paper, but he really doesn't discuss the math behind the $3$-form, $\langle \phi_g[\phi_g\wedge\phi_g]\rangle$, but will go back and check again.

Comment: If $G$ is compact and simple, then $H^3(G;\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$, with generator the 3-form you have written down.  This follows from the isomorphism between $H^3(G;\mathbb{R})$ and $H^3(\mathfrak{g})$, with $\mathfrak{g}$ the Lie algebra of $G$.

Comment: (And the calculation of $H^3(\mathfrak{g})$, of course!)


Comment: Thanks for the info, do you have a reference by any chance? 

Comment: Look at the one of the volumes of Connections, Curvature, and Cohomology by Grueb et al; perhaps vol. 2 titled "Lie Groups".

Comment: The general story (for non-simply connected Lie groups) is: the (exponentiated) WZ-term is the holonomy of a gerbe-connection around the worldsheet. The 3-form is the curvature of the gerbe-connection. You may look into papers of Gawedzki, e.g. "WZW branes and gerbes". 

Comment: This question was also asked on math.SE and in the meantime a further pointer to the literature has been added in an answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/cartan-3-form-on-a-lie-group-g

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Theodore Frankel's Geometry of Physics. There is a section on the gauge group . The cartan three form is the three form from the Chern Simons term at a flat connection. A flat connection is when the potential A is equal to the $g^{-1}dg$. In the Chern Simons 3 form you have A^A^A. At pure gauge this becomes $Tr(g^{-1}dg\wedge g^{-1}dg\wedge g^{-1}dg)$. This term is proportional to the cartan 3 form. I hope this helped.